# Matplotlib animation MovieWriters fails on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, ffmpeg, matplotlib

I am attempting to save matplotlib animations to a movie via `ffmpeg` on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32-bit Desktop).  Following the matplotlib [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example_writer.html), it fails to load the animation writer: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'writers'` (line 15 of the example):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def update_line(num, data, line):
    line.set_data(data[...,:num])
    return line,

# Set up formatting for the movie files
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
```

Via `apt-get`, I've tried installing ffmpeg, every codec imaginable, and even tried to compile ffmpeg from source.  Nothing works.

How do I get `matplotlib` to talk to ffmpeg on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the `unbuntu` packaged version of `matplotlib` it is `1.1.1rc1`. The attribute `writers` was added about 3 months after that tag, and is in versions `1.2` and later.

You can either install `matplotlib` from source (this is what I do, it's not too bad) or use the [daily ppa](https://launchpad.net/~takluyver/+archive/matplotlib-daily).

My advice for compiling from source is to use the packaging system for as many of the dependencies as possible and install `matplotlib` by hand (if you do want to use pip [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863775/python-scipy-install-on-ubuntu/11864996#11864996)) as such

```
git clone git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
cd matplotlib
git checkout -b v1.2.0
python setup.py install --prefix=/home/username/local_installs/
```

(which will get you the latest stable version) then make sure the path where it got installed is in your `$PYTHONPATH` which can be done by including the line

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/username/local_installs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH
```

in your `~/.bashrc` file.  You might have to vary that line a bit depending on which version of python you use.  You might need to do this (and make sure folders exist) before `setup.py` will be happy.

Comment: maybe the simplest way to install it is to use pip and a virtualenv. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11864996/1301710

Comment: @bmu added your link to the main text

Comment: @tcaswell Second time in a week you've helped me out.  Thanks!  It's funny how obvious the answer is when you read it... I simply didn't consider that the packaged version was not up to date.

Comment: @jjwebster glad to help.  If the answers solved your problem could you possibly accept them (the check symbol on the left)?  Selfishly, I get rep, and un-selfishly it helps people in the future that have the same question as you know that you found the answer useful.

Comment: @tcaswell You got it.  I didn't know the "check" was where the rep came from... I thought it was the up-vote (which I can't do until I get to 15 rep of my own...)

Comment: @jjwebster rep comes from both.  You also get 2 rep for accepting an answer.  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation