# Matplotlib drawings not shown as non-root user

Tags: python, matplotlib

Knowing that this is a question, 100times asked, but no solution helps me.

Trying to make a simple plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as p 
p.plot(range(20), range(20))
p.show()
```

I used several backends in ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc, such as GTK, GTKAgg, Qt4Agg, gdk, agg, svg, kairo,...), by adding the line

```
backend: <backend>
```

But nothing happens when I try to plot. No error message, simply nothing. I used both the standard console python2.7 and the IPython console.

I'm using CentOS with Gnome Desktop. Matplotlib is 1.2.0.

Do you have any ideas?

NOTE: I realized that it is a problem only as non-root user.

Comment: Works for me, matplotlib 1.20 on Ubuntu. I don't have a file `.matplotlibrc` though (i.e. it's empty)

Comment: By the way import Tkinter; Tkinter.Tk() works fine for me. No problem with that package. This is really sxxx :(

Comment: do `dir(p)` and `help(p.plot)` work?

Comment: Both works fine, and as I am realizing at this moment. Its a security problem. I cannot plot as normal user but need root rights? Is this, because I compiled matplotlib as root? How to handle that?

Comment: that shouldn't be a problem. I've used matplotlib installed by myself on ~/.local/... and the one shipped with Ubuntu without problems

Comment: How did you install mpl?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803044/matplotlib-animation-moviewriters-fails-on-ubuntu-12-04/14806555#14806555 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863775/python-scipy-install-on-ubuntu/11864996#11864996 for two ways to install `matplotlib` as non-root.

Comment: Well, I have the same symptoms since installing matplotlib 1.2.0, except root doesn't see any drawings/figures/plots either ): I'm guessing I've a dependency problem, but havn't worked out what's missing yet...